# Given original string and encoded string, how to induce encoding?

Tags: algorithm, character-encoding, sml

Suppose I have an original string and an encoded string , like the following:

"abcd" -> "0010111111001010", then one possible solution would be that "a" matches with "0010", "b" matches with "1111", "c" matches with "1100", "d" matches with "1010".

How to write a program, that given these two strings, and figure out possible encoding rules?

My first scratch looks like this:

```
fun partition(orgl, encode) =
let
    val part = size(orgl)
    fun porpt(str, i, len) =
        if i = len - 1 then
            [substring(str, len * (len - 1), size(str) - (len - 1) * len)]
        else
            substring(str, len * i, len)::porpt(str, i + 1, len)
in
    porpt(encode, 0, part)
end;
```

But obviously it can not check whether the two substrings match the identical character, and there are many other possibilities other than proportionally partitioning the strings.

What should be the appropriate algorithms for this problem?

P.S. Only prefix code is allowed.

---

What I have learned has not really got into serious algorithms yet, but I did some searching about backtracking and wrote my second version of the code:

```
fun partition(orgl, encode) =
let
    val part = size(orgl)
    fun backtrack(str, s, len, count, code) =
        let
           val current =
               if count = 1 then
                  code@[substring(str, s, size(str) - s)]
               else
                  code@[substring(str, s, len)]
        in
           if len > size(str) - s then []
           else
              if proper_prefix(0, orgl, code) then
                  if count = 1 then current
                  else
                     backtrack(str, s + len, len, count - 1, current)
              else
                 backtrack(str, s, len + 1, count, code)
        end
 in
    backtrack(encode, 0, 1, part, [])
 end;
```

Where the function proper_prefix would check prefix code and unique mapping. However, this function does not function correctly.

For example, when I input :

```
partition("abcd", "001111110101101");
```

The returned result is:

```
uncaught exception Subscript
```

FYI, the body of proper_prefix looks like this:

```
fun proper_prefix(i, orgl, nil) = true
  | proper_prefix(i, orgl, x::xs) =
    let
      fun check(j, str, nil) = true
        | check(j, str, x::xs) =
          if String.isPrefix str x then
             if str = x andalso substring(orgl, i, 1) = substring(orgl, i + j + 1, 1) then
                check(j + 1, str, xs)
             else
                false
          else
             check(j + 1, str, xs)
    in
      if check(0, x, xs) then proper_prefix(i + 1, orgl, xs)
      else false
    end;
```

Comment: Do you assume that this is a [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)? Do you assume that all bit strings have an equal length? Do you assume that all characters map to a unique bit string? These assumptions drastically affect the problem and consequently any algorithm for determining the translation.

Comment: Yes. This is a substitution cipher, which may not have equal length - that's why I said my first scratch is awful since it assumes the character would have equal length. And yes, the mapping should be injective.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try a back-tracking approach:

Start with an empty hypothesis (i.e. set all encodings to unknown). Then process the encoded string character by character.

At every new code character, you have two options: Either append the code character to the encoding of the current source character or go to the next source character. If you encounter a source character that you already have an encoding for, check if it matches and go on. Or if it doesn't match, go back and try another option. You can also check the prefix-property during this traversal.

Your example input could be processed as follows:

```
Assume 'a' == '0'
Go to next source character
Assume 'b' == '0'
Violation of prefix property, go back
Assume 'a' == '00'
Go to next source character
Assume 'b' == '1'
...
```

This explores the range of all possible encodings. You can either return the first encoding found or all possible encodings.

Answer (score 1):

If one were to naively iterate all possible translations of *abcd* → 0010111111001010, this possibly leads to a blow-up. Simple iteration also appears to lead to a lot of invalid translations one would have to skip:

```
(a, b, c, d) → (0, 0, 1, 0111111001010) is invalid because a = b
(a, b, c, d) → (0, 0, 10, 111111001010) is invalid because a = b
(a, b, c, d) → (0, 01, 0, 111111001010) is invalid because a = c
(a, b, c, d) → (00, 1, 0, 111111001010) is one possibility
(a, b, c, d) → (0, 0, 101, 11111001010) is invalid because a = b
(a, b, c, d) → (0, 010, 1, 11111001010) is another possibility
(a, b, c, d) → (001, 0, 1, 11111001010) is another possibility
(a, b, c, d) → (0, 01, 01, 11111001010) is invalid because b = c
(a, b, c, d) → (00, 1, 01, 11111001010) is another possibility
(a, b, c, d) → (00, 10, 1, 11111001010) is another possibility
...
```

If all character strings contain each character exactly once, then this blow-up of results is the answer. If the same character occurs more than once, this further constrains the solution. E.g. matching *abca* → 111011 could generate

```
(a, b, c, a) → (1, 1, 1, 011) is invalid because a = b = c, a ≠ a
(a, b, c, a) → (1, 1, 10, 11) is invalid because a = b, a ≠ a
(a, b, c, a) → (1, 11, 0, 11) is invalid because a = b, a ≠ a
(a, b, c, a) → (11, 1, 0, 11) is one possibility
... (all remaining combinations would eventually prove invalid)
```

For a given hypothesis, you can choose the order in which to verify your constraints. Either

1. See if any mappings overlap. (I think this is what Nico calls the prefix property.)
2. See if any character that occurs more than once actually occurs in both places in the bit string.

An algorithm using this search strategy will have to find an order of checking constraints in order to try to a hypothesis as soon possible. My intuition tells me that a constraint *a* → β is worth investigating sooner if the bit string β is long and if it occurs many times.

Another strategy is ruling out that a particular character can map to any bit string of/above/below a certain length. For example, *aaab* → 1111110 rules out *a* mapping to any bit string of length above 2, and *abcab* → 1011101 rules out *a* mapping to any bit string of length different than 2.

For the programming part, try and think of ways to represent hypotheses. E.g.

```
(* For the hypothesis (a, b, c, a) → (11, 1, 0, 11) *)

(* Order signifies first occurrence *)
val someHyp1 = ([(#"a", 2), (#"b", 1), (#"c", 1)], "abca", "111011")

(* Somehow recurse over hypothesis and accumulate offsets for each character, e.g. *)
val someHyp2 = ([(#"a", 2), (#"b", 1), (#"c", 1)],
                [(#"a", 0), (#"b", 2), (#"c", 3), (#"a", 4)])
```

And make a function that generates new hypotheses in some order, and a function that finds if a hypothesis is valid.

```
fun nextHypothesis (hyp, origStr, encStr) = ... (* should probably return SOME/NONE *)
fun validHypothesis (hyp, origStr, encStr) =
    allStr (fn (i, c) => (* is bit string for c at its
                            accumulated offset in encStr? *)) origStr

(* Helper function that checks whether a predicate is true for each
   character in a string. The predicate function takes both the index
   and the character as argument. *)
and allStr p s =
    let val len = size s
        fun loop i = i >= len orelse p (i, String.sub (s, i)) andalso loop (i+1)
    in loop 0 end
```

An improvement over this framework would be to change the order in which to explore hypotheses, since some search paths can rule out larger amounts of invalid mappings than others.